# Why header value isn't inserted into Apache Camel's `to` url parameter of the route in Spring DSL?

Tags: java, apache-camel, mqtt, camel-spring-dsl

We have a route that will accept the kafka.KEY and use that as mqtt url parameter to send the data to the right topic.

```
<routes
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="KafkaToMQTT">
        <from uri="kafka://mqtt?brokers=localhost:9092"/>
        <to uri="micrometer:timer:camel.proxy.kafka.mqtt.stream?action=start"/>
        <log message="Headers ${header.kafka.KEY}"/>
        <to uri="mqtt:mqtt?host=tcp://localhost:1883&amp;publishTopicName=try${header.kafka.KEY}"/>
        <to uri="log://camel.proxy?groupInterval=3&amp;level=INFO"/>
        <to uri="micrometer:timer:camel.proxy.kafka.mqtt.stream?action=stop"/>      
    </route>
</routes>
```

In the log messages I see the ${header.kafka.KEY} correctly, while in the mqtt I'm getting the topic as literally `try${header.kafka.KEY}`

What is the reason for that, how to make the header to be used there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid that the right element instead of `to` should be used, that is `toD`.

`toD` concatenates the url correctly, so the right route XML is:

```
<routes
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="KafkaToMQTT">
        <from uri="kafka://mqtt?brokers=localhost:9092"/>
        <to uri="micrometer:timer:camel.proxy.kafka.mqtt.stream?action=start"/>
        <log message="Headers ${header.kafka.KEY}"/>
        <toD uri="mqtt:mqtt?host=tcp://localhost:1883&amp;publishTopicName=ESP_02/try${header.kafka.KEY}"/>
        <to uri="log://camel.proxy?groupInterval=3&amp;level=INFO"/>
        <to uri="micrometer:timer:camel.proxy.kafka.mqtt.stream?action=stop"/>      
    </route>
</routes>
```